# Python: How to create new identical list object?

Tags: python, list

The following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def func(listtt):
    a.reverse()

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
print a, b

func(a)
print a, b

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a + []
print a, b

func(a)
print a, b
```

produces the output of:

```
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1] [3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1] [1, 2, 3]
```

I understand that in the first example, a and b both point to the same list. My question is how do I create a new identical list object? If i have a list, is b = a + [ ] the best way to create two separate but identical instances of the list? I want to create two variables that point to two different lists/objects that have the exact same values. How do I do that?

Also, how do I know which operations create a new list and which change the current list? I know append changes the list and addition adds the two lists and creates a new one. I found a list of possible operations in https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types, but which operations do which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a shallow copy of a list:

```
b = a[:]  # There are various other options such as list(a), copy.copy(a) etc.
```

`a` and `b` are now identical, but don't point to the same reference.

---

The ones that modify the list in-place will be methods of `list`, such as `.sort()`. You know that a new value is being assigned if it is done with the `=` operator.

Comment: Alternatively you could do: `new_list = copy(old_list)`. That might be semantically cleaner than the slicing trick, but both will work. This question has been asked a lot of times already and I am pretty sure you could have found the answer with a simple search.

Answer (score 2):

There is lot of things to copy or clone a list:-

> - You can slice it:
>
>   new_list = old_list[:]
>
>   [Alex Martelli's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Martelli) opinion (at least back in 2007) about this is, that it is a weird syntax and it does not make sense to use it ever. ;) (In his opinion, the next one is more readable).
>
>   - You can use the built in `list()` function:
>
>     new_list = list(old_list)
> - You can use generic `copy.copy()`:
>
>   ```
>   import copy
>   new_list = copy.copy(old_list)
>   ```
>
>   This is a little slower than list() because it has to find out the datatype of old_list first.
> - If the list contains objects and you want to copy them as well, use generic `copy.deepcopy()`:
>
>   ```
>   import copy
>   new_list = copy.deepcopy(old_list)
>   ```
>
> Obviously the slowest and most memory-needing method, but sometimes unavoidable.

For more details, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/).